# Combining multiple input arrays in to single array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

**How to combine multiple arrays in to single array ?**

Here's my code:

```
while($row = db_fetch_array($query)) {

        print_r($row);        

        //foreach($row as $value) {
        //   $to_gid = $value['to_gid'];
        //   //unset($value['to_gid']);
        //   $new_gid[$to_gid][] = $value;
        //}
}
```

**EDITED:**

print_r prints the below output:

```
    Array
(
    [to_gid] => 6012
)

Array
(
    [to_gid] => 8227
)

Array
(
    [to_gid] => 8227, 6012
)
```

But my expected o/p is :

```
Array
(
    [to_gid] => 8227, 6012
)
```

commented foreach is the thing what i have tried :-(

What should i need to do to achieve this?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

to combine multiple arrays you have to have multiple arrays, not multiple objects.

```
$new_gid = array();
while($row = db_fetch_assoc($query)) { //I hope you have such a function
    $new_gid[$row['to_gid']][] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is what you are looking for.